# How to use tf.image.resize_with_pad but pad with ones instead of zeros?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

According to Tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_with_pad), the padding is always with zeros instead of ones.

Is there there a way to change the padding to ones?

If not, what is the best alternative for a tensorflow dataset?

Here is my code example:

```
def resize_with_pad(image, label):
    
    image = tf.image.resize_with_pad(image=image,
                                     target_height=resized_wh,
                                     target_width=resized_wh,
                                     method=ResizeMethod.BILINEAR,
                                     antialias=False)
    return image, label


def create_tf_dataset_pipeline(tf_dataset):
    
    tf_dataset = tf_dataset.map(load_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    tf_dataset = tf_dataset.map(normalize, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    tf_dataset = tf_dataset.map(resize_with_pad, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    tf_dataset = tf_dataset.batch(batch_size)
    tf_dataset = tf_dataset.prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    
    return tf_dataset
    

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train_filepaths, y_train_class))
train_data = create_tf_dataset_pipeline(train_data)
```

I tried resizing and padding the images and saving it in a directory (i.e. frontloading the processing), but that is very inflexible as I need to create a new dataset every time I want to train a model on a different size. It would be much better if I could do it dynamically with tensor flow.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a temporary solution.

You can change the function `def pad(..., constant_values=0)` in the `array_ops.py` file,
somewhere under your tensorflow library's folder like `..\EnvsName\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py`, to `def pad(..., constant_values=255)` and save.

Then you can pad with WHITE background ([255,255,255], or you said "ones") when you call the function `tf.image.resize_with_pad`.